# maven-deploy-plugin deploy show percentage uploaded

Tags: maven

Is there any way to get Maven deploy to output the percentage uploaded or megabytes uploaded to the console?

I'm using Maven 3.0.5. I've tried pass the -X option but still nothing

Comment: If you look at the output you can see things like `Uploaded: http://xyz/content/repositories/snapshots/xyz-jar (35 KB at 1097.1 KB/sec)` ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen when running maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file it just goes straight from Uploading to Uploaded but I want percentages in between these statements since it can look frozen if it's a large file